# Is it possible to overload C++11 new operator to create smart pointer instead?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I want to use C++11 smart pointers always, with traditional pointer syntax (which a little similar to Java syntax) , because I don't want to worry about memory management , I think it's good idea to overload new operator with custom one, in other words

Instead of create new object dynamically like this :

```
    obj *o = new obj();
```

which create traditional pointer to obj, I want to make it create smart pointer , like this

```
    obj *o = new obj(); // o will be deleted automatically
```

How do I make something like this ?

**Note :** I don't want to replace the original new operator ,I just want to overload my own class one.

Thanks .

Comment: I don't think that's such a good idea. The standard syntax for creating C++11 smart pointers (and objects wrapped by them) is already very simple. Using traditional non-smart pointer syntax in its place will only confuse readers of your code.

Comment: You can just use `std::shared_ptr<obj>` or `std::unique_ptr<obj>` instead of  `obj*`

Comment: @jogojapan every C++ standard there are new ways to create object , for example in C++14 there is make_unquie() method! , I want to use one syntax and also keep using recommended standard things ,because of that I want to make my uniform method , then any time there is change i C++ standard I should change this method only without change all my library code.

Comment: `auto o = std::make_unique<obj>();` seems simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

As long as you have `obj *o = new ...` you're still returning a plain pointer and not a new type.

A new type (a smart pointer class) is required so that you can use the destructor to deallocate the memory. If all you have is a plain pointer -- you have to `delete` it manually.

(It is possible to come up with a global garbage collector -- each new allocation will be recorded there, the global GC will be called periodically scanning for memory regions that are no longer pointed to and deallocating them).

Comment: But I want to use uniform way, because C++11 has std::unique_ptr<obj> and C++14 has std::make_unique<obj>(),I heard in C++17 std::auto_ptr will return :-/

Comment: @AhmedTajElsir Who told you `auto_ptr` will return? It's been removed entirely.

Comment: Anyway I hope there is a way to do such a uniform way, and when there is a change , just change the core function

Comment: @T.C. What you mean ? I think you don't understand me.